# Javascript browser SOAP HTTP Headers

Tags: javascript, http, soap, header

I encounter a problem in calling a SOAP API from a ReactJS app; a sample code that i'm using :

```
const $ = require("jquery");
const soap = require('soap-everywhere');

import cookie from 'react-cookies';

class Phonebook {
    list () {
        const url = 'http://url/to/wsdl';
        let args = {
        };
        console.log(soap);
        soap.createClient(url, (err, client) => {
            client.list(args, (err, result) => {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = new Phonebook();
```

And I would like to pass custom HTTP Headers which are stored in browser cookies like :

```
"IPBX_SESSION": cookie.load("IPBX_SESSION"),
"IPBX_MODE": cookie.load("IPBX_MODE")
```

But in this browser soap module, it seems there is no method to add custom HTTPHeaders in a way where it could be like :

```
client.addHTTPHeaders({
    "IPBX_SESSION": cookie.load("IPBX_SESSION")
});
```

This is a custom SOAP API on which we have not all the control, we only have access to the web server options.